# Not able to create ABAP structure to use /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize

Tags: json, serialization, abap

My json file looks like:

```
{
    "1489402": {
        "Category": "Program error",
        "CorrectionInstructionsObjectList": [{
            "ObjectName": "/SCMB/CL_IM_ORG_CHECK         IF_EX_HRBAS00_RELAT~MAINTAIN_RELATION",
            "ObjectType": "METH",
            "ProgramID": "LIMU"
        }, {
            "ObjectName": "/SCMB/MP556100_F01",
            "ObjectType": "REPS",
            "ProgramID": "LIMU"
        }, {
            "ObjectName": "/SCMB/GET_ORG_STRUCTURE",
            "ObjectType": "FUNC",
            "ProgramID": "LIMU"
        }],
        "CurrentStatus": "Released for Customer",
        "PrimarySAPComponent": "tm-md-org",
        "ReleasedOn": "16.07.2010"
    }
}
```

I want to create a corresponding ABAP structure in my report so that I can consume this json file and map it into the structure. I want to use /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize but I am not able to fugure out what should be the receiving ABAP type.

```
 /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize( EXPORTING json = lv_json_content
                               pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case
                               CHANGING data = lt_data ).
```

In other words what should be the structure of lt_data.

Comment: JSON object is like an ABAP structure, and JSON array is like an internal table, and all JSON properties that you use are of type String. Simple. But my concern is about "1489402", is it variable or fixed?

Comment: Its a actually a variable. Is there a way to create a type which can support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't answer your question because I don't master `/ui2/cl_json`, but I propose another solution.

As rule of thumb, I wouldn't recommend to use `/ui2/cl_json` because it's not officially supported by SAP as far as I know (it's just an initiative of one SAP employee), but to use XSLT or SAP Simple Transformation language (preferred). I go for XSLT because ST is impossible to use due to the dynamic property name "1489402" in the JSON file.

1. Create an XSLT transformation
2. The ABAP program calls the transformation

Note that when the transformation source is JSON, SAP converts it into SAP [JSON-XML](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_json_xml.htm) format (tags like `<object>`, `<array>`, `<str>`).

The XSLT transformation must return XML in SAP [asXML](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_xslt_asxml.htm) format if the transformation result is an ABAP variable (i.e. `RESULT root = variable`, not `RESULT XML variable`).

XSLT transformation `Z_OBJECTS`:

```xml
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/object/object">
    <asx:abap xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" version="1.0">
      <asx:values>
        <ROOT>
          <ITEM_NAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </ITEM_NAME>
          <CATEGORY>
            <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='Category']"/>
          </CATEGORY>
          <OBJECT_LIST>
            <xsl:for-each select="array/object">
              <item>
                <OBJECT_NAME>
                  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='ObjectName']"/>
                </OBJECT_NAME>
                <OBJECT_TYPE>
                  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='ObjectType']"/>
                </OBJECT_TYPE>
                <PROGRAM_ID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='ProgramID']"/>
                </PROGRAM_ID>
              </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </OBJECT_LIST>
          <CURRENT_STATUS>
            <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='CurrentStatus']"/>
          </CURRENT_STATUS>
          <PRIMARY_SAP_COMPONENT>
            <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='PrimarySAPComponent']"/>
          </PRIMARY_SAP_COMPONENT>
          <RELEASED_ON>
            <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='ReleasedOn']"/>
          </RELEASED_ON>
        </ROOT>
      </asx:values>
    </asx:abap>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

ABAP program:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_object,
         object_name TYPE string,
         object_type TYPE string,
         program_id  TYPE string,
       END OF ty_object,
       ty_object_list TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_object WITH EMPTY KEY,
       BEGIN OF ty_item,
         item_name             TYPE string, " will contain "1489402"
         category              TYPE string,
         object_list           TYPE ty_object_list,
         current_status        TYPE string,
         primary_sap_component TYPE string,
         released_on           TYPE string,
       END OF ty_item.
DATA(json) = `{    "1489402": {`
    && `        "Category": "Program error",`
    && `        "CorrectionInstructionsObjectList": [{`
    && `            "ObjectName": "/SCMB/CL_IM_ORG_CHECK         IF_EX_HRBAS00_RELAT~MAINTAIN_RELATION",`
    && `            "ObjectType": "METH",`
    && `            "ProgramID": "LIMU"`
    && `        }, {`
    && `            "ObjectName": "/SCMB/MP556100_F01",`
    && `            "ObjectType": "REPS",`
    && `            "ProgramID": "LIMU"`
    && `        }, {`
    && `            "ObjectName": "/SCMB/GET_ORG_STRUCTURE",`
    && `            "ObjectType": "FUNC",`
    && `            "ProgramID": "LIMU"`
    && `        }],`
    && `        "CurrentStatus": "Released for Customer",`
    && `        "PrimarySAPComponent": "tm-md-org",`
    && `        "ReleasedOn": "16.07.2010"}}`.
DATA(item) = VALUE ty_item( ).
CALL TRANSFORMATION z_objects SOURCE XML json RESULT root = item.
```

NB: so that to write the XSL transformation, you need to know the JSON-XML of a given JSON. You may use the `ID` transformation to know it. Example:

```
DATA(json) = `{"a":[1,"s"]}`.
DATA(json_xml) = ``.
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE XML json RESULT XML json_xml OPTIONS xml_header = 'no'.
ASSERT json_xml+1 = `<object><array name="a"><num>1</num><str>s</str></array></object>`.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. If the json file contains more than one record then I get the error while calling the transformation that xml format is invalid

Comment: Should the XSLT transformation be modified in order to take multiple records ?

Comment: You should adapt both the transformation and the type of the data object if the JSON is different. I guess your actual JSON starts with `[{"1489402":{` instead of `{"1489402":{`, consequently you should have `<ROOT><xsl:for-each select="array/object"><item><ITEM_NAME>...` and `DATA item TYPE TABLE OF ty_item.` If you have questions about XSLT, SAP JSON XML or SAP ASXML, or CALL TRANSFORMATION, please search or ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72336109/not-able-to-consume-json-file-using-xslt?noredirect=1#comment127791790_72336109

Comment: I have added explanations about JSON-XML in my answer so that you better understand the concept of transformations with JSON as input. When asking a question, please just indicate minimal reproducible code (full JSON/XML is not needed in your case), what you get and what you expect. See Help Center.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The XSLT you have given before works perfectly for one record but if there are more than 1 obj num then it doesnt. I tried your suggestion <ROOT><xsl:for-each select="array/object"><item><ITEM_NAME>. but it did not work. I am fetching the file from local system using gui_upload and appending it into a string but when passing it to the transformation it dumps. Could you help me with modifying the XSLT for multiple records.

Comment: The suggestion was for `[{...`. I can't guess your actual JSON. Please ask questions according to the rules of Stack Overflow (see Help Center). If not, please use classic forums like https://answers.sap.com.

Comment: I pasted the actual json on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72336109/not-able-to-consume-json-file-using-xslt?noredirect=1#comment127791790_72336109  . I could not edit the one here. Is it possible for you to have a look? Thanks again

Comment: You must understand the rules of Stack Overflow to use it. If you don't, I already advised. The only thing I can do is to ask the question myself the right way, and answer to it, that's a lot of work unfortunately.

Comment: `I pasted the actual json on stackoverflow.com/questions/72336109/…` you posted an invalid JSON, the end tag is missing and probaly the starting tag is also incorrect. Always [check the payload](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) before you post it

Comment: @SandraRossi Where do you get the information from that /ui2/cl_json is an SAP employee's personal initiative and not supported by SAP? It is used in numerous places in SAP's own code.

Comment: @mydoghasworms It's not because SAP is using it internally that they will support if you have bugs with it (only very few objects can be used by customers = "released" objects). I'm incorrect in saying "it's just an initiative of one SAP employee", even if Alexey Arsenyev presented his class in a [wiki](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/One+more+ABAP+to+JSON+Serializer+and+Deserializer) (which doesn't exist anymore). But now [it's released in ABAP Cloud since 2020](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12699592/does-ui2cljson-work-in-abap-cloud.html). It's not released in non-Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this, it shall work. Pay attention to two additional flags for deserializing which control the processing of associative arrays and also name mappings for comfortable renaming.

```
  TYPES:
    BEGIN OF ts_cio,
      object_name TYPE string,
      object_type TYPE string,
      program_id  TYPE string,
    END OF ts_cio,
    BEGIN OF ts_error,
      category              TYPE string,
      ci_list               TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ts_cio WITH DEFAULT KEY,
      current_status        TYPE string,
      primary_sap_component TYPE string,
      released_on           TYPE d,
    END OF ts_error,
    BEGIN OF ts_dump,
      id    TYPE i,
      error TYPE ts_error,
    END OF ts_dump,
    tt_dump TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ts_dump WITH UNIQUE KEY id.

  DATA: lt_data TYPE tt_dump.

  /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize( EXPORTING json = lv_json
                                       pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case
                                       assoc_arrays = abap_true
                                       assoc_arrays_opt = abap_true
                                       name_mappings = VALUE #(
                                        ( abap = `CI_LIST` json = `CorrectionInstructionsObjectList` )
                                        ( abap = `PROGRAM_ID` json = `ProgramID` )
                                        ( abap = `PRIMARY_SAP_COMPONENT` json = `PrimarySAPComponent` ) )
                             CHANGING data = lt_data ).
```

Comment: This is by far the simpler solution and if it was my question, I would have accepted this as the right answer. Pity I can't vote for it again.